# Why I'm getting all 1s in keras when I use model.predict?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use LSTM, in the keras package. I normalize all my training and test data, to a scale between 0 and 1. I reshape the array into a 3D array. But when I run to see the results, I get an array of 1s, instead of a scaled value between 1 and 0.

Here is my code:

```
Input = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')

for i in range(0, len(Input['Gold Price'])):
   Input['Gold Price'][i] = float(Input['Gold Price'][i].replace(',',''))
   Input['DJIA'][i] = float(Input['DJIA'][i].replace(',',''))

x_train = Input[['DJIA', 'Silver Price', 'Copper Price', 'US Dollar Index', 
'VIX']]
y_train = Input[['Gold Price']]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 0.95))
scaler_x = scaler.fit(x_train)
scaler_y = scaler.fit(y_train)
x_scaled = scaler_x.transform(x_train)
y_scaled = scaler_y.transform(y_train)

x_scaled = np.reshape(x_scaled, (x_scaled.shape[0], 1, x_scaled.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(5, activation='relu', input_dim=5))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='mae',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_scaled, y_scaled, epochs=5, batch_size=32)

Test = pd.read_csv('Test Prices Daily.csv')

for i in range(0, len(Test['DJIA'])):
    Test['DJIA'][i] = float(Test['DJIA'][i].replace(',',''))

x_test = Test[['DJIA', 'Silver Price', 'Copper Price', 'US Dollar Index', 
'VIX']]

scaler_x = scaler.fit(x_test)
x_scaled_test = scaler_x.transform(x_test)

x_scaled_test = np.reshape(x_scaled_test, (x_scaled_test.shape[0], 1, 
x_scaled_test.shape[1]))
prediction = model.predict(x_scaled_test, batch_size=128)
```

Comment: Perhaps just remove this line worth a shot `scaler_x = scaler.fit(x_test)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))
```

Is the offending line. The activation should be sigmoid.

The reason is that softmax is given by

softmax( x)_i = e^x_i / sum_i e^x_i

which normalises your output vector such that the components sum to 1 (i.e. maps it onto a simplex). With 1 component output, then it must always be 1.

Also I am slightly surprised to see this:

```
loss='mae'
```

And think that binary cross entropy is a superior choice as your response is between 0 and 1.  I guess it depends on the interpretation of the output variable as either a function approximation or a probability, which is something I know not.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But, now all my outputs are the same. Anyway to fix that?